# Why is onChange={ ( content ) => setAttributes( { content } )} now used?

Tags: block-editor

Looking through older tutorials or code for blocks built in 2018/2019 vs the more current blocks, I see two different ways attribute values are set.

For example, the "old" way for an attribute called "content" might be:

`onChange={ (newContent) => setAttributes({ content: newContent })}`

Whereas in a more modern block:

`onChange={ ( content ) => setAttributes( { content } )}`

I get it's a minor change but I'm curious if anyone here knows why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `{ content }` is shorthand for `{ content: content }` it's a JS thing not a WordPress thing.

Both methods work and do the same thing, but the `{ content }` syntax is shorter, so the variable was named `content` in newer examples to allow it.

Otherwise, there are no security or performance improvements, it's just a shorter syntax for the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If you want to read up on it a bit more, [here is a link to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015). You'll find more resources on it with the term "Shorthand property names".